# Alternate definition for uncountable sum of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

The standard way to define the sum of an uncountable number of reals is to set
$$ \sum_{\alpha \in A} x_{\alpha}  = \sup \left(\left\{ \sum_{\alpha \in S} x_{\alpha} ~|~ S \subset A ~\text{and}~ |S| ~\text{finite} \right\}\right) .$$

I feel uneasy doing this, as we are using *finite* sums to approximate an *uncountable* sum, meaning we skipped a whole cardinality.

To this end, would it be unreasonable to set
$$ \sum_{\alpha \in A} x_{\alpha} = \sup \left(\left\{ \sum_{i = 0}^\infty x_{n_i} ~|~ n_i \in S ~\text{are all distinct and the sum is convergent} \right\}\right) ?$$

Comment: what could you deduce from?

Comment: Is that a standard way? It seems to say that the sum of the numbers in $S=(-1,0)$ is equal to zero?? Anyway, it is a standard exercise to show that according to your definition any uncountable set of positive numbers has infinity as its sum. Including convergent series won't change that.

Comment: To elaborate on @JyrkiLahtonen's comment, that's the standard way of defining an uncountable sum of *nonnegative* reals; there is no standard definition, as far as I know, when both positive and negative reals are allowed.

Comment: Not to mention, if the index set $A$ is uncountable but all but finitely many terms $x_\alpha$s are zero, this "standard" sum fails to match the usual finite sum, for the same reason Jyrki, Noah bring up.

Comment: I assume OP is only considering nonnegative terms.  In that case, the two definitions are equivalent, but the first one is simpler.  I'd note also that that countably infinite sums are themselves defined in terms of finite sums, so you're still defining everything in terms of finite sums.